# my first ADD / Subract on MySQL

Tags: mysql

Given a table that looks like this:

```
| Book in Shelves | Arrived Books | Borrowed Books | Total Books |
        15               10                5              ?
```

How can I add the first three columns and have the total appear in the `Total Books` column?

```
Book in Shelves + Arrived books - Borrowed Books = Total Books
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While designing a database, you don't store values that can be calculated from other values. This will make your database inconsistent. For example: if you updated the `Book in Shelves` to 20, you will have to add another query to edit the `Total Books`. So don't ever add a column which you can calculate. When retrieving the data from your database, you could do the following:

```
SELECT `Book in Shelves`, `Arrived Books`, `Borrowed Books`, (`Book in Shelves` + `Arrived Books` - `Borrowed Books`) AS `Total books` FROM `table`;
```

Results:

```
+-----------------+---------------+----------------+-------------+
| Book in Shelves | Arrived Books | Borrowed Books | Total books |
+-----------------+---------------+----------------+-------------+
|              15 |            10 |              5 |          20 |
|              44 |            22 |              5 |          61 |
|              12 |             2 |              7 |           7 |
+-----------------+---------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: wow you really enlighten my mind sir Hamza. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You mean update 'total books' by the calculation you provided below?
Try this:

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET total_books=(books_in_shelves+arrived_books-borrowed_books)
```

You can also use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).

'PHP and MySQL for dummies' is a good book in my opinion. But some internet tutorials at Lynda.com for example are helpful too!

Comment: I'm not a fan of the `UPDATE`, since it's easy to calculate the total value from the other columns.  Using triggers is a good way to get around that issue in some capacity.

Comment: sir archie im taking up JAVA, NETBEANS, MySQL Road. you know any e-BOOK for this stuff?